# What is Rikulo dart really?

Tags: dart, rikulo

I have been reading the abstracts on the website http://www.rikulo.org but all those cryptic vague statements do not help me. The examples are all about visuals.

I do not understand what this framework is capeable of doing. The big picture is missing.

1. What kind of apps can i build with rikulo?
2. Is there any access to the hardware?
3. Can is use the smartphones sensordata and send e.g. coordinates from my smartphone to a web service?
4. What are the limitations?

Comment: I wrote to the Rikulo guys about this. I expect that they'll answer the questions asked soon.

Comment: Sorry, I have to agree with the vagueness of the [tag:Rikulo] site.  The proposal looks good and so and such the ideas are sound from my looking at github, etc. But I feel there are steps missing and someone who know about the technology needs to edit and proof the documentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As described in [this blog](http://blog.rikulo.org/posts/2012/Jul/General/the-rikulo-way/), Rikulo is aimed to provide a structured UI model for Web and mobile programming. We are the same team who developed [ZK](http://zkoss.org). With Rikulo, we'd like to take a step further since many things have been changed since we developed ZK in 2005. Also, both Dart and HTML 5 are young. It is an excellent moment to explore the best possible UI architecture for both Web and mobile programming.

For example, we use absolute positioning to give programmers 100% control the layout of UI rather than spending hours to figure out why it fails in certain combination. Another example is "recursive layered structure", such as layout manager and visual effect handling -- rather than ad hoc features targeting specific problems individually.

On the other hand, we don't have many widgets yet. It might be the reason that confused you. As a Apache licensed project, we hope we can have an active community for building widgets and addons, as long as we can really provide a solid and elegant architecture -- it is what we focus now and keep refining.

To access the hardware, you can use [Rikulo Gap](http://docs.rikulo.org/rikulo/latest/Rikulo_Gap/Fundamentals.html) which is based on Cordova/PhoneGap. To communicate back the server, you can use Web socket or [HttpRequest](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/HttpRequest.html). We will have more advanced support for jsonizing, caching and communicating Dart objects between client and server, but it is not ready yet.

Technically, there is no limitation. Of course, the current number of widgets is definitely not enough, but it will get more in the near future. Furthermore, you always can create them with HTML 5 (and contribute back). However, for mobile applications, one thing you have to keep in mind: the performance won't be as good as the apps written in Objective C. The good is Rikulo is cross platform and your app can be accessed with Web browsers and as a native app.

Comment: It would be a good idea to communicate the vision more clearly (e.g. examples) on the web site.

Comment: Please consider: [Wanted: Rikulo UXL example(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608569/want-rikulo-uxl-example).